# How to remove a particular value of a property in a JSON object in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I know how to remove a particular property form a JSON object using Remove() but i am looking to remove a particular value of a property in a JSON object

```
{
    "name":  "new-report",
    "resources":  {
                      "repositories":  [
                                           {
                                               "Name":  "test"
                                           },
                                           {
                                               "Name":  "CentralLogger-Nuget-Local"
                                           },
                                     ]  
                  }
 }
```

I want to remove {     "Name":  "test"    } this entry where ever it is

Final JSON should be

```
{
    "name":  "new-report",
    "resources":  {
                      "repositories":  [
                                    
                                           {
                                               "Name":  "CentralLogger-Nuget-Local"
                                           },
                                     ]  
                  }
 }
```

Comment: "where ever it is" in the `repositories` property or anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to remove that object from the `repositories` property then its quite straight forward, just need to filter all objects where the `Name` property is not equal to `test` and assign the new value to the property.

Assuming the Json has been already converted into an object and is stored in the `$json` variable:

```
$json.resources.repositories = @($json.resources.repositories | Where-Object Name -NE Test)
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
```

Comment: I dont have a new property to add, instead i want to remove that enry completely instead of having a null/empty value

Comment: @wehelpdox your question is unclear. if you add how you expect the json to look like as a result I might be able to help

Comment: i updated in the question

Comment: @wehelpdox your expected output is exactly what this answer is accomplishing

Comment: if i have to change the value from test to something else?

Comment: @wehelpdox just change the `Test` value here `Where-Object Name -NE Test` to whatever you want to exclude